# Express request type mismatch

Tags: node.js, express

I use Express middleware to check request type, but I'm getting surprising results, here is my middleware code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method);
    next();
});
```

And here is console output I get:

```
POST
GET /parse/login 404 528.160 ms - 57
```

What can cause such behaviour and what can be the way to avoid it?

Comment: Did you also log the `req.url` to make sure the path matches?

Comment: @mscdex, yes, I logged it, path is different, it's just "/", what can cause such behaviour?

Comment: Without seeing more code, my guess is that you have some middleware that is causing a redirect when there is either no session or authentication to a login page.

Comment: @mscdex, thanks for help